# How to calculate the percentage in eloquent?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

please have a look at the problem. You will find it interesting. 
I have a table `member` in which I have a column `result`. In this result column three values can be possible and at one time only one value can be used. The value that are possible `W`, `L` and `V`. Forget about the `V` as it is not required here.

Let's say, I have 5 rows and in 3 rows I have `W` and in 1 row I have `L` and last one is `V`.

So here 3W and 1L out of 4(W+L together). So the percentage of W is 75%. How can I calculate it using mysql and if it is possible using eloquent would be better.

Currently, I am using this solution 
1. Getting all the rows 
2. Running php loop 
3. And based on the value of the result column I am calculating the percentage. works fine. But I think if there are better solution why not to find it :)

Hope you have something for this problem. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want a pure Eloquent solution, do this:

```
$wl = Member::whereIn('result', ['W', 'L'])->count();
$total = Member::count();
$percent = $wl / $total * 100;
```

This will be much more efficient than actually retrieving any records from DB.

Comment: Just more than perfect. But I needed to edit a bit more to calculate it correctly but you are a boss :). Thanks 

edit I did 
`$wl = Member::where('user_id', 1)->whereIn('result', ['W'])->count();
        $total = Member::where('user_id', 1)->where('result','!=','V')->count();
        $percent = $wl / $total * 100; `

Comment: beware of the division by zero if total is zero !

Comment: @Sliq though you are technically accurate...if there were 0 members, would anyone ever see it?

Answer (score 6):

Your question is a bit vague, but from what I see the `COUNT` function should be sufficient here:

```
SELECT
    100.0 * COUNT(W) / COUNT(*) AS w_pct,
    100.0 * COUNT(L) / COUNT(*) AS l_pct
FROM yourTable;
```

Of course, if you are already doing an aggregation then we can modify the above query to include `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1):

And what if the $total=0? In this scenario dividing by zero will give an error.
Make sure to check it as well like:

```
if ($total != 0) {
$percent = $wl / $total * 100;
} else {
$percent = 0;
}
```

I hope you will find it helpful in the future.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel Join query with count percentage:

```
select('marketplace.store_name', 'users.name' , **DB::raw('round((count(products.user_id)/(select count(*) from products)*100),2) as percentage')** , DB::raw('round(avg(products.user_id),2) as avg') );
```

I hope this helps.